# Implement a pagination class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pagination

So my task is:

Implement a pagination class helpful for arranging text on pages and listing content on the given page. The class should take in a text and a positive integer, which indicate how many symbols will be allowed per page (take spaces into account as well).

You need to get the number of whole symbols in the text, get the number of pages that came out and the method that accepts the page number, and return the number of symbols on this page. If the provided number of the page is missing, raise an exception with the message "Invalid index. Page is missing".

Implement searching/filtering pages by using symbols/words and displaying pages with all the symbols on them. If the provided symbols/words are missing, raise an exception with the message "'<symbol/word>' is missing on the pages".

If you're querying by a symbol that appears on many pages or if you are querying by the word that is split in two, return an array of all the occurrences.

Pages indexing starts with 0.

The code must work this way:

```
>>> pages = Pagination('Your beautiful text', 5)
>>> pages.page_count
4
>>> pages.item_count
19

>>> pages.count_items_on_page(0)
5
>>> pages.count_items_on_page(3)
4
>>> pages.count_items_on_page(4)
Exception: Invalid index. Page is missing.
>>> pages.find_page('Your')
[0]
>>> pages.find_page('e')
[1, 3]
>>> pages.find_page('beautiful')
[1, 2]
>>> pages.find_page('great')
Exception: 'great' is missing on the pages
>>> pages.display_page(0)
'Your '
```

My starting code is:

```
class Pagination:
    def __init__(self, data, items_on_page):
        pass

    def page_count(self):
        pass

    def count_items_on_page(self, page_number):
        pass

    def find_page(self, data):
        pass
    
    def display_page(self, page_number):
        pass
```

Can you help me please?

---

Comment: You forgot to post how you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Paste this whole thing into ChatGPT for a good start.

Comment: It is unethical to ask us to do your homework for you.  It's also unethical to ask ChatGPT to do it.  This is not hard -- give it a try, then come to us.  `item_count` is clearly just `len`, `page_count` is `len` divided by `items_on_page`, rounded up.  None of this is hard.